# Custom Entry not showing on Tkinter multiple window

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a custom Entry "self.name_e" on the second window "Demo 2" but anytime I run the code the custom entry only shows up on the first window "Demo 1"...
self.name_e is used to receive the entry on Window 2 "Demo 2"
The AutocompleteEntry is the custom Entry class that is used by windows two
How do I fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk

#To shorten the code for perfect readability I chose to remove the content of the AutocompleteEntry class   
class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):...
 
class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.master.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        autocompleteList = [ 'Milo tin', 'Shito small' ]
        def matches(fieldValue, acListEntry):
            pattern = re.compile(re.escape(fieldValue) + '.*', re.IGNORECASE)
            return re.match(pattern, acListEntry)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.master.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        
        #AutocompleteEntry is a custom Entry which is also a class on it own
        self.name_e = AutocompleteEntry(autocompleteList, listboxLength=10, width=20, font=('arial 18 bold'), matchesFunction=matches)
        self.name_e.place(x=350, y=150)

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You aren't passing the `master` parameter to your `AutocompleteEntry`.  Without that, it becomes a child of the root window by default.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you very much...but I still got a problem. The entry box shows on the second window now but the entry list still shows on the root window

Comment: @jasonharper This is the init of the AutocompleteEntry class tho  `def __init__(self, autocompleteList, *args, **kwargs):`